# Mysql truncating decimals

Tags: mysql

I have a decimal type field im MySQL and I'd like to truncate it in a query to a specifiv number of decimals:

fields DDL:

```
<!-- language=sql -->
`discountprice` decimal(14,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
```

If I select the value it displays with 4 decimals but if I truncate it to 2 decimals, then all the decimals are gone. Why?

This will output: 14000.0000

```
<!-- language=sql -->
SELECT ipr.discountprice AS 'nettoegysar'
```

While this is: 14000

```
<!-- language=sql -->
TRUNCATE(ipr.discountprice, 2) AS 'nettoegysar'
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `ROUND()` function instead like below which will round it to 2 decimal places.

```
SELECT ROUND(ipr.discountprice, 2) AS 'nettoegysar'
```